# I am trying to echo my array options randomly with php

Tags: php, regex, random

Hello I am trying to echo 14 different array's and shuffle the images so they are generated randomly inside of a preg_Replace function.
Can anyone help me with this?

```
<?php

//islamic
$islamicart_array = array('/images/islamicart/IA.jpg', '/images/islamicart/IS(2).jpg',     '/images/islamicart/IS(3).jpg', '/images/islamicart/IS(4).jpg', '/images/islamicart/IS(5).jpg', '/images/islamicart/IS(6).jpg', '/images/islamicart/IS(7).jpg', '/images/islamicart/IS(8).jpg', '/images/islamicart/IS(9).jpg', '/images/islamicart/IS(10).jpg');

//pme-postmodernism/expressionism
$pme_array = array('/images/pme/E.jpg', '/images/pme/E(2).jpg',  '/images/pme/E(3).jpg',   '/images/pme/E(3).jpg',  '/images/pme/E(4).jpg');

//http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp
$myfile = file_get_contents('http://www.guardiannews.com');

$myfile = preg_replace('/<a      href=".*?" /', '<a target="_top"     href="/course/s12/projects/me/"', $myfile);

echo($myfile);

?>
```

So with this code, I am trying to echo an image randomly on another page.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck, what's the code we're supposed to help you with?

Comment: What does OSX have to do with php? retagging + paste some code - what You've already done, and what is not working and why.

Comment: Yes I can help you with this. Tell me what to do?

Comment: we realy need a crystal ball function on SO ;)....more seriously, can you descripe a bit more what you are trying to do and give us some code example?

Answer (score 3):

[Shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Usage:

```
$arr = array('image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg');
var_dump($arr);
shuffle($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

With the lack of context, attempt and code, I can't seriously help you further, so just giving you a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Could give each image a number and then randomize a number using rand() and displaying the number of the image it is connected to.